# How can I stop/start IISADMIN with powershell

Tags: powershell

I have multiple servers that need to have the IISADMIN service restarted. I need to do this remotely, so I have code that will ask for credentials. however when I get to the point of stopping it and restarting it, it fails because the dependant services. I am trying to use IISRESET /STOP, but cannot get it to function.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. if you need to see the code let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have PowerShell 2.0 available I would use its remoting capabilities.  You also have to admin to use iisreset (at least on Vista/WinServer 2008 and above).  Fortunately PowerShell remoting takes care of that (requires you to be admin too).  :-)  With PowerShell 2.0 I would try something like this:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Invoke-Command server1,server2,server3 -ScriptBlock { iisreset.exe /restart } `
               -cred $cred
```

If the `iisreset.exe` still isn't working try PowerShell's `Restart-Service` in its place:

```
Restart-Service w3svc -Force
```

But first you have to have PowerShell 2.0 on each remote machine and enable remoting on each remote machine via the commands:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
```

If you can't do PowerShell 2.0 on the remote machines, you could always use [psexec.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx).

Comment: Doesn't powershell remoting require iis to be running?  When I try to "Invoke-Command ... iisreset" I get a nasty error saying WinRM is not running.